# Too long question title breaks the page

Tags: bug, questions, design

Recently I came across this question: [void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277654/void-android-support-v7-widget-searchview-setonquerytextlistenerandroid-support).

I found that it the actual breaks question page!

Please check below screen shot of Firefox browser:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this isn't bug. Who want to write 100+ char title without any space? I think this will be tagged as Status-By-Design

Comment: Apparently someone does.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260146/questions-with-long-titles-and-no-spaces-in-it-show-the-scroll-bars-when-display and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235164/long-title-with-no-spaces-flows-into-the-sidebar and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292797/title-goes-beyond-the-border

Answer (score -2):

I **don't think** that this is a bug from **UI side**. This should be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

This isn't a good title any more. Title should be clear. Writing  100+ char char without spacing never become clear.

But this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) **from Backend**. Adding this type of question should be validated when question is asked. Don't allow to use word(word mean anything without space) if any word length is 50, 60 or any good value.